# Binding Button IsEnabled to TextBox.CanUndo

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a button to a textbox's CanUndo property, except that I can't get it to work. I tried a direct binding like

```
IsEnabled="{Binding CanUndo, ElementName=txtDocument}"
```

But that didn't work. Button stayed disabled even after typing in textbox which would change the CanUndo property to true.

I also tried

```
<Button IsEnabled="False" >
    <Button.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="Button">
               <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanUndo, ElementName=txtDocument}" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                      </DataTrigger>

               </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
    <Image Source="/Images/32/undo.png" />
</Button>
```

I also tried with two separate datatriggers, one for enabled true and one for false, but still didn't work. Am I missing something fundamental? Like maybe this property doesn't raise the required events for binding changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Button's command property to the [ApplicationCommands.Undo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.undo.aspx) command and specify the CommandTarget property to be the TextBox.

The button will set the IsEnabled property based on ApplicationCommands.Undo command CanExecute state. The button will be disabled when CanExecute is false and enabled when CanExecute is true.

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox x:Name="txtDocument">Test
  </TextBox>
  <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtDocument}" Content="Undo"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Wow, nice! Works perfectly, and I don't have to add my own event or command. Cheers!